# Flexbox not providing intended margins

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My list is (somewhat) successfully calling flexbox's space-around alignment, except the first-child of the footer list in question has a relatively larger margin on it's left. Cannot figure this out and would rather not risk its future with a cheat.  Here's the code; any input helps, thank you:

```
#footer {
  width: 75%;
  background: dimgray;
  height: 150px;
/*  position: relative;
*/  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

  #footer ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;

  }

   #footer li {
    width: 30%;
    height: 130px;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid white;
   }
```

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ul element automatically gets a default padding from the browser.

```
#footer ul {
   padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: do not wrap `li`s with a `div`.

Comment: @Jason would like to make sure I understand exactly what you're saying here, as you look like a guru

Comment: @Alex - a `div` wrapper for `li`s is invalid HTML. `li` can only be wrapped by `ul`, `ol`, `nav`, and `menu` (i think that's it), but definitely not by `div`. to modify your markup to make it invalid simply because you don't understand how to correctly fix your CSS is a mistake.

Comment: @Jason Thanks, is this just a precaution? A little confused as I don't have them wrapped in a div.

Comment: @Alex i know, the answer here was recommending you do so.

Comment: @Jason ahh, cool, sorry, hadn't seen the pre-edit answer, thanks again